# copy value until last full row in next column

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste

I need to copy the value of one cell (A1 lets say) on column B from B1 until the last used row in column C (C15 let's say - This means that I need to copy from B1 to B15)

So far I don't have any code - Im a beginner

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) I think you may have misunderstood how stackoverflow operates. You may want to see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please post what you have tried so far. Keep these in mind while posting **1.** What were you expecting? **2.** What is not working? Include Error message if applicable and we will take it from there. Did you try recording a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using VBA as below

```
Sub fill()
  'counting last row in Column C
  lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

  'copying Range A1 to all cells on Column B until last row in Column C
  Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lrow, 2)).Value = Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much rangrarj r! Your code needed to define the variable lrow, but with that added it worked. I copy the final solution here:Sub fill()
Dim lrow As Integer
  'counting last row in Column C
  lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
  Range("A12").Value = lrow


  'copying Range A1 to all cells on Column B until last row in Column C
  Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lrow, 2)).Value = Cells(1, 1)
End Sub

Comment: excel vba dynamically defines variables btw, can you accept the answer or upvote it